# how to find the fundamental routine for creating a new process using _do_fork()?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I am new to Linux and I have been assigned this

In Linux kernel sources, Find _do_fork(), the fundamental routine for creating a new process

- What is the purpose (give a high-level description) of copy_process() ?
- Within copy_process, what exact code guards against fork() bombs?
  can somebody help me out?

Comment: The _do_fork function is in kernel/fork.c as shown here https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.5/source/kernel/fork.c#L1691

This is an online resource to look at the source code of Linux. For the rest I recommend reading this book https://doc.lagout.org/operating%20system%20/linux/Understanding%20Linux%20Kernel.pdf Especially from page 117 which exactly answers your question.

Comment: thank you @user123 let me look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, elixir.bootlin.com is a very good resource for looking at the source code of Linux. It has a very good search engine. I've been looking at the source code and I think I found the code which does what you are looking for (related to fork bombs prevention).

In kernel/fork.c in the copy_process() function you find the following lines:

```
if (atomic_read(&p->real_cred->user->processes) >=
            task_rlimit(p, RLIMIT_NPROC)) {
        if (p->real_cred->user != INIT_USER &&
            !capable(CAP_SYS_RESOURCE) && !capable(CAP_SYS_ADMIN))
            goto bad_fork_free;
}
```

This code does an atomic_read of the current `task_struct` structure (p) being copied. It reads the member real_cred which is a struct of type `cred` defined in include/linux/cred.h. This struct contains a member named user which is a struct of type `user_struct` defined in include/linux/sched.h. This user_struct contains a member named processes which is an atomic_t which is itself a struct containing one member (an int). So processes is basically an int which tells the kernel how much processes a user have. The code above checks this member against the value returned by task_rlimit() function. If the limit is exceeded, it cancels the whole thing. Hosnestly, I don't completely understand the if in the middle. But you can always look for details in the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to know that `fork()` will use system call and find interrrupt function from Interrupt table which is named as 'sys_fork()`, which is like below

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE0(fork)
{
......
    return _do_fork(SIGCHLD, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, 0);
}
```

So the core of fork is [`_do_fork()`](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/kernel/fork.c.html#_do_fork)

This function will do two major work

- call `copy_process()` to copy structure of process/thread in kernel, which named as `task_struct`
- call `wake_up_new()` to wake up the task